# Can I reorder using CSS / HTML or do I need JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, sidebar

I am working on a webpage which has a sidebar and a main section. The CSS / HTML essentially look like this:

```
<html><head>
<meta name="viewport"
  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<style>
#sidebar {
    float: right;
    min-width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: Red;
}
#content {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    #sidebar {
        float: none;
    }
}
</style></head>
<body>
<div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

So the idea is that when displayed side-by-side, the content `div` takes up the width of the window not used by the sidebar, but when we move to mobile sized screens the sidebar `div` stops floating and moves inline.

This is fine for the desktop site, but on the mobile site, because I have put my sidebar `div` before my main `div`, the sidebar appears first, and I want it to appear below.

Is there an easy / generally practised solution to this that doesn't involve using javascript to move the `div`s around after load? Should I be taking a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. There are two ways you can go about it:

### Legacy solution

Put your sidebar after your content and `float:right` your main content container on desktop size. This way the sidebar will be on the left on desktop but displayed after the main content on mobile.

```css
body {margin: 0;}
.main-wrapper >*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 200px;
}
#sidebar {
  background-color: Red;
  min-width: 30%;
  max-width: 30%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
#content {
  background-color: #999;
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  #content,#sidebar  {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: initial;
    max-width: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    content
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </div>
</div>
```

### Modern solution

Use <kbd>[order](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp)</kbd> (flexbox).

```css
body {margin: 0;}
.main-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
          flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
      -ms-flex-align: stretch;
          align-items: stretch;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#sidebar, #content {
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 30%;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 30%;
          flex: 0 0 30%;
}
#content {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
      -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
          flex: 1 0 auto;
}
@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .main-wrapper{
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  #sidebar, #content {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 100%;
        -ms-flex: 1 0 100%;
            flex: 1 0 100%;
  }
  #sidebar {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -webkit-order: 1;
        -ms-flex-order: 1;
            order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the first one doesn't quite do it as I want the sidebar to be on the right and also I think it means I have to set a specific width on the sidebar, when I'd rather just set a min-width? That's to allow the sidebar's contents to stretch it if they need to. I need to have more of a think about the second one.

Comment: I've set sidebar `220px` because you have, in your example. It's possible to make it grow and shrink proportionally with the layout width, but it's not a very common or practical solution (you'll probably run into display problems with whatever you show on sidebar). I updated both examples.

Comment: I didn't quite get the first to work properly, which probably explains why the second solution has been made! Flex works well for me, thanks very much, I particularly liked the ability to set the flex width to 0 so that it just takes a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

For this, if you want to make the development easier and with limited use of JavaScript I recommend you take a look at the Bootstrap framework. This implements a new and intuitive class system that allows for dynamic scaling through CSS classes in your HTML instead of JavaScript.

Take a look, it's becoming pretty standard for many webpages and what you want should be pretty easy to do with the framework.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Thanks, and I know bootstrap is very powerful. However, I'm pretty new to these web technologies and I'm trying to start from the bottom and learn how to do this in plain CSS / HTML. If bootstrap has solved this problem I guess I could go and have a look there, unless you already know..?

Comment: Hey, no worries at all. That's fair enough for working up from the bottom, once you have a good understanding of CSS, it may be worth moving on and learning powerful frameworks like Bootstrap, as essentially, it just offers a good extension to CSS to enhance your websites. Bootstrap would solve this problem very quickly with the grid based element system, else, looking at the above answers to do it pure CSS would aid you too:)